# df.loc para encontrar valores comunes

Tags: python

No sé como encontrar los jugadores NBA que están actualmente (Club) en el mismo equipo que debutaron (Debut deportivo). En pyspark sé que se utiliza la función when, pero en python no sé como hacerlo y me da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas , tienes mal la sintaxis, busca en la documentación de pandas para aprender más al respecto.

Comment: df.loc[df["Club"]==df["Debut deportivo"]] es lo que buscas

Comment: ¿Pero se utiliza la función .loc? Ahora leeré más detenidamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si, iba a ponerte como escribirlo pero di enter en el cel y se envió antes, en mi siguiente comentario te pase como se usa loc para este caso

Comment: Iba "cerca" de encontrar la solución, pero creo que me falta añadir la columna nombres para que me muestre los nombres de los jugadores. Gracias. Muy amable

Comment: Recuerda compartir la solución cuando te funcione, saludos

Comment: Ya lo he validado. Si quisiera usar la función .apply en este caso sería así: df_debutantes = df[['Club', 'Debut deportivo']].apply(' '.join, axis=1) ?

Comment: no parece que tenga mucho sentido en realidad, que es lo que estas intentando hacer?

Comment: Guardar en la variable df_debutantes de tipo DataFrame la información sobre qué jugadores coincide el nombre del Club en el que juega y 'club_debut'. Es decir, los jugadores que aún juegen en el equipo en el que debutaron.

Comment: Pero con el loc ya es suficiente, en ese punto ya tenés solo las filas que cumplen esa condición, si guardas df.loc[df["Club"]==df["Debut deportivo"]] en una variable y lo printeas vas a ver que solo quedan esas

Comment: df.loc[df["Club"]==df["Debut deportivo"]]
print(df_debutantes)

Me sale esto:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(goles), Altura, Apodo(s), Club, Debut, Debut deportivo, Deporte, Dorsal(es), Entrenador, Goles en clubes, Liga, Nacimiento, Nacionalidad(es), Nombre completo, Nombre de nacimiento, Pareja, Part., Part. (goles), País, Peso, Posición, Retirada deportiva, Selección, nombre]
Index: []

Comment: Eso es porque parece que ningun elemento de el dataframe cumple la condición, asi que te devolvió una lista vacía, agregale una fila artificialmente que cumpla la condición para hacer la prueba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función de `loc` se usa aparte de para aplicar la condición, para actualizar el valor para una columna / grupo de columnas de las filas que cumplen la condición. Si no lo vas a actualizar entonces no hace falta utilizar `loc`, con esto sirve.

```
df[df["Club"] == df["Debut deportivo"]]["Nombre"]
```

Si en cambio lo quieres actualizar usa esto:

```
df.loc[df["Club"] == df["Debut deportivo"],"Nombre"] = "NuevoValor"
```

Para aclarar un poco el funcionamiento, `df["Club"]==df["Debut deportivo"]` devuelve un vector columna con valores `True` o `False` indicando si se cumple o no la condición. Al hacer `df[indices]` lo que haces es indexar y te muestra las filas que cumplen la condición, por eso si te quieres quedar únicamente con los nombres tienes que añadir `["Nombre"]` al final. Espero que te sirva!